# Prisma increase count by 1 after Find query

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am trying to count how many times a record was viewed by users by managing a field called `views` in the table. I want to increase the count every time a record is pulled to be sent by the API.

What's the right and fastest way to do it while not blocking the thread to return the data to the frontend.

> Stack: NextJS and Prisma

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [atomic number operations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#examples-61) in this case.

```
await prisma.model.update({
  where: { id: 'some-id' },
  data: { value: { increment: 1 } }
})
```

Comment: thanks. a modified version of this worked.